# How can we catch an event emit of an event emitter in a pipe of rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have to catch the event emit of an event emitter in a pipe and perform some operations on the basis of that one.

Below is the snippet of code of both the html and ts file.

xyx.component.html

```
    <div *ngIf="count | async as count">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <div>{{ count.counter }}</div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="start" (click)="start.emit()">
      &nbsp;
      <input type="button" value="stop" (click)="stop.emit()">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

xyx.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'xyz-app',
  templateUrl: './xyz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xyz.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class XYZComponent {
  public readonly count: Observable<{
    counter: number,
  }>;

  public readonly start: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
  public readonly stop: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.count = interval(1000).pipe(
      map(counter => counter + 1),
      startWith(0),
      map(counter => ({counter})),
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do in the pipe to catch that event emit and perform the start and stop operation of counter.

Answer (score 0):

the annular pipe has a job of transform the data , the async pipe do the job of subscribe to observable of it and unsubscribe when the component destroy.

you can do the job of stop and start by assign null to 'count' observable and assign to new observable in case of start

but you can also do the job by rxjs operator like `takeUntil, repeatWhen`

```js
  counter: Observable<number>;
  start = new Subject();
  stop = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.counter = interval(1000).pipe(
      map(counter => counter + 1),
      startWith(0),
      takeUntil(this.stop),
      repeatWhen(() => this.start)
    );
  }
```

check this [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oufzgk)

Comment: Thanks man for helping me out.
But as when i stop and starts again, It gets started from 0, 
but i want it to start from the count where I stopped.

Comment: @UmeshSharma I don't know if there is an operator we can used to start next time with old value  

Comment: Okay,
So is there any operator that can start the timer only when I clicked the start button.
Means the timer should get active only when the start is clicked, other wise it should only show 0.

Comment: Yeah: you just instantiate the Observable when the button is clicked ^^

Comment: @UmeshSharma check this updated demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gby192